# Getting the specific value from website using excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, web, web-scraping

I'm trying to use Excel VBA to get the specific text from a website. But I don't know how to do it. Please help!

I want to get the highlighted html element's value, "52.05":

[image]

This is my code:

```
rowNum = 10
While rowNum < 51
    Do
        DoEvents
        Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    Set doc = ie.document
    On Error Resume Next

    output = doc.getElementById("yfi_quote_summary_data")
    Sheet1.Cells(rowNum, "E").Value = output

    rowNum = rowNum + 1
    ticker = Sheet1.Range("B" & rowNum).Value
    ie.navigate "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=" & ticker
Wend
ie.Quit
```

Comment: Comment out the `On Error Resume Next`  - what happens when you run your code ?  Also: tons of similar questions (with answers) already asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vba+google+finance

Comment: I want some example in my case. One Error Resume Next: Specifies that when a run-time error occurs, control goes to the statement immediately following the statement where the error occurred.

Comment: I *know* what it does, which is why I suggested you comment it out.

Comment: Can you show me some code to illustrate how to get that value please?

Comment: You want me to show you how to comment out that line?

Comment: In terms of the HTML document, can you describe what identifies the 52.05 value as the one you want to retrieve? How can you tell it apart from the other values in the document - 52.86, 53.00, 53.07?

Comment: @barrowc i think it;s by their class name and id name

Comment: My own thoughts are that it's the value in the `td` element which comes immediately after the `th` element containing the text "Prev close:" Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, how can I retrieve that value?

Comment: Easiest would be to leverage `getElementsByClassName`, since you want items with class name `yfnc_tabledata1`, if you have that method available to you.

Comment: @Porcupine911 I tried that, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
Sub Get_Values()
Dim RowNum As Long
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim ticker As String
Dim MainDocument As IHTMLDocument
Dim TableHTML, PrevClose As Object
Set ie = New InternetExplorer

ie.Visible = True

RowNum = 10

    ticker = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & RowNum).Value
    ie.navigate "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=" & ticker

While RowNum < 51
    'LOOP UNTIL EMPTY COLUMN "B"
    Do Until Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & RowNum).Value = ""

    'WAIT FOR PAGE LOAD
    Do While Not ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    Loop

    'SET PAGE VARIABLES
    Set MainDocument = ie.document
    Set TableHTML = MainDocument.getElementById("yfi_quote_summary_data")

    'FIND "PREV CLOSE" SECTION OF TABLE
    For Each tableheader In TableHTML.getElementsByTagName("th")
        If tableheader.innerHTML = "Prev Close:" Then
        Set PrevClose = TableHTML.getElementsByTagName("td")(0)
        Sheet1.Cells(RowNum, "E").Value = PrevClose.innerHTML
        Exit For
        End If
    Next tableheader

    'CONTINUE TO NEXT ROW
    RowNum = RowNum + 1
    ticker = Sheet1.Range("B" & RowNum).Value
    ie.navigate "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=" & ticker

    Loop
Wend

ie.Quit

End Sub
```

To get the `Bid` value, simply change this line in your code.

```
If tableheader.innerHTML = "Prev Close:" Then
```

Change this to

```
If tableheader.innerHTML = "Bid:" Then
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. It works perfect. However, I don't understand how it works. 1. Can you explain it to me please? 2. Where can I find some tutorials about this topic? 3. How come when I get the value "53.00" in "<span id "yfs_b00_msft" 53.00> span</span>", I just need to use getElementById("yfs_b00_msft").innerText ?

Comment: hi, I am glad to know it works well. Please mark as the correct answer if it has helped you.

Comment: In regard to tutorials, I struggled to find some myself. The best way to learn is to practice :)

Comment: Please see my edited code above, as to how to get the `Bid` value

Comment: Thank you. I already marked it as correct answer. I just confuse about the parent and child relationship. Base on some posts, first I need to find the parent and then look for the child. I just got confused in this part. Maybe I need to study a little bit html?